# How to set uv values read from a file to a mesh created in blender script?

Tags: python, blender, mesh, uv-mapping

I am adapting an old script  to blender 2.6, the script reads  mesh data from a custom file type and then creates a mesh array with that data.

I achieve to make all but set the uv values of each vertex to the mesh.

I create the mesh array like this:

```
for i in range(0,numeroparts):
    malla.append(bpy.data.meshes.new(name="2k_Part"+str(i)))
    uv = []
    xyz= []
    for j in range(0,numerovertxpart[i]):
        line=file.readline()
        x,y,z,u,v=float(line.split()[0].replace(',','.')),float(line.split()[1].replace(',','.')),float(line.split()[2].replace(',','.')),float(line.split()[3].replace(',','.')),float(line.split()[4].replace(',','.'))
        uv.append((u,v))
        xyz.append((x,y,z))
        print(x,y,z)


    aa = []
    bb = []
    cc = []
    faces= []               

    for j in range(0,numerofacexpart[i]):
        line=file.readline()
        a,b,c=int(line.split()[0]),int(line.split()[1]),int(line.split()[2])
        faces.append((a,b,c))
        aa.append(a)
        bb.append(b)
        cc.append(c)
        print(a,b,c)

    malla[i].from_pydata(xyz, [], faces)





    for q in range(len(malla[i].polygons)):
        #malla[i].faces[q].mode |= Blender.Mesh.FaceModes['TWOSIDE']
        #malla[i].faces[q].transp = Blender.NMesh.FaceTranspModes['ALPHA']
        #malla[i].faces[q].uv=Mathutils.Vector(uv[aa[q]]), Mathutils.Vector(uv[bb[q]]), Mathutils.Vector(uv[cc[q]])
```

My problem is here:

```
for q in range(len(malla[i].polygons)):
        #malla[i].faces[q].mode |= Blender.Mesh.FaceModes['TWOSIDE']
        #malla[i].faces[q].transp = Blender.NMesh.FaceTranspModes['ALPHA']
        #malla[i].faces[q].uv=Mathutils.Vector(uv[aa[q]]), Mathutils.Vector(uv[bb[q]]), Mathutils.Vector(uv[cc[q]])
```

I don´t know how to set the uv values, the lines commented is how I did it for blender 2.49